# Failure to generate an AUC result for a classification model using Python 3.7 in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, classification

Here is the error message I get when the Python code below is entered. This code came from a machine learning ebook and I simply altered it to match the data set **ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.**

## Cross Validation Classification ROC AUC

```
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
df = pd.read_csv('Diabetes_Classification.csv')
array = df.values
X = array[:,0:14]
Y = array[:,14]
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
scoring = 'roc_auc'
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
print("AUC: %.3f (%.3f)" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Comment: Print out the set of values in the y_true variable. From the error you are having its clear to me that you have only one label in y_true

Comment: Thanks. print(y_true) does not generate any results

Comment: Print out Y instead of y_true! This is what you are using for doing cross_val_score

Comment: That prompts the following error message ValueError: y_true contains only one label (0.0). Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. The y outcome is diabetes = 1 and no diabetes = 0. I'm not sure why it says it onlly contains one label?

Comment: That's what I thought, print out your dataframe and check if the Y is actually what you meant to predict.

Comment: It has something to do with K fold =10. After reading some Stackflow posts I decided to decrease it to 3 and everything worked. I think because there is class imbalance it focused on the majority class = 0 and not the class = 1. Thanks

Comment: Right, I think in some of the fold you had only 0.0 classes which threw the error you saw